# Actions SDK dialogflow nodejs transactions API example without sandbox

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I tried an example from Actions SDK transactions API Nodejs from [this](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs) and adapt to my real project
but I want to delete the "sandbox" watermark from my receipt like this image

[image: sandbox watermark in testing app]

so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

after I try from alpha tester preview (not from developer preview), I see that sandbox watermark is disappear.